# How many up to date copies of the SVN repo are there?

Tags: svn

I have a SVN repository, that I access from about 7 machines. I would like to determine if one of these machines has not had and `svn update` or `svn commit` in a long time (> 2 weeks). Is this something I can determine at server side, by means of a script?

I am trying to avoid the scenario whereby one machine is constantly committing & updating, leaving the others hopelessly out of date. Thanks.

Comment: You might be able to do this, but surely the solution to your scenario is to talk to the developers on your team?

Comment: No team, just me. I'm using SVN for my documents and a bunch of code. I was thinking about a mechanism to do this as a crude backup solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tool which is doing this..
basically SVN does no bookkeeping on checked out working copies.
As you can move and copy workingcopies freely without checking them out at the server I doubt a working solution is possible.

Also SVN has no mechanics for identifying different workingcopies except by username.

So the only thing you can do is scanning apache logfiles and filter by ip addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Oli Charlesworth that this situation smells funny, but you can run `svn status -u` on each machine's working copy to see if it has any files that will be changed by an update. See the [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html) for more information.